# LightFM does the training set need to be the same size as the test set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm working on a pure collaborative filtering model in LightFM using a simple user-item matrix.

When I have a training matrix that has more rows than the test matrix, I encounter this error: "Incorrect number of features in user_features"

It seems this is caused by line 789 in lightfm.py:

```
if not user_features.shape[1] == self.user_embeddings.shape[0]:
    raise ValueError('Incorrect number of features in user_features')
```

Investigating this - it looks like it is being caused by line 778 in lightfm.py:

```
n_users, n_items = test_interactions.shape
```

Which suggests the size of the test dataset should match the train. And making them the same size does fix my error.

How can I persuade LightFM to let me have train and test datasets of different sizes?

Comment: I would change the *wording*. Often in ML, the rows are the samples and in this interpretation your single row-sample is a tuple or something similar (user, item, value). The number of rows in test and train surely has no limitation! But there is one in terms of *dimensions*. So only in terms of dimensions (which users and which items are observed) those datasets need a 1:1 correspondence. That's maybe a strong assumption, but you can imagine the problem predicting user 11, where there was no user 11 in training (there is no latent-vector which was build).

Comment: Thank you @sascha for the clear and detailed response.